# Pytorch on GCP: Machine type is not available on this endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, mlops

I'm new to GCP so pardon for prehaps asking/missing something obvious here.

I'm trying to deploy and create a version resource on GCP with a custom pytorch model. Everything have been working fine until now until I try to create the a new version of the model. Then I keep getting:
**INVALID_ARGUMENT: Machine type is not available on this endpoint.**

I've tried switching between different types from their list [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction#available_machine_types) without luck. What am I missing?

Here's the script I run to deploy:

```
MODEL_NAME='test_iris'
MODEL_VERSION='v1'
RUNTIME_VERSION='2.4'
MODEL_CLASS='model.PyTorchIrisClassifier'
PYTORCH_PACKAGE='gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/packages/torch-1.8.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl'

DIST_PACKAGE='gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/models/Test_model-0.1.tar.gz'
GCS_MODEL_DIR='models/'
REGION="europe-west1"


# Creating model on AI platform
gcloud alpha ai-platform models create ${MODEL_NAME}\
--region=europe-west1 --enable-logging \
--enable-console-logging

gcloud beta ai-platform versions create ${MODEL_VERSION} --model=${MODEL_NAME} \
    --origin=gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/${GCS_MODEL_DIR} \
    --python-version=3.7 \
    --machine-type=mls1-c4-m2\
    --runtime-version=${RUNTIME_VERSION} \
    --package-uris=${DIST_PACKAGE},${PYTORCH_PACKAGE} \
    --prediction-class=${MODEL_CLASS}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, since you specified an endpoint for creating your model `--region=europe-west1`, you also should specify the same endpoint when creating a version of your model with the flag `--region=europe-west1`, [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#create_a_model_version). Also, it is written in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/regional-endpoints#create-model-version) that, you can only omit the `--region` flag from `versions create` command when the model was created in a global endpoint. Please, let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I tried to set the region on both model and versions create without luck, but setting the region to global solved it. 

Now I get this error, found multiple open treads for this, any idea?

``` ERROR: Create Version failed. Bad model detected with error:  "Failed to load model: User-provided package Test_model-0.
1.tar.gz failed to install: Command '['python-default', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--target=/tmp/custom_lib', '--no-cache-dir', '-b', '/tmp/pip_builds', '/tmp/custo
m_code/Test_model-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Error code: 0)" ```

Comment: Could you please post another question so we address one issue at a time? You can send the link to the question here. Also, in order to further contribute to the community I will post an answer based on the information I shared. I would appreciate if you can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines), you can only deploy a ***Custom prediction routine*** when using a [legacy (MLS1) machine type](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/machine-types-online-prediction#differences) for your model version. However, you can not use a regional endpoint with this type of machine, as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/regional-endpoints#understanding_regional_endpoints),

> - Regional endpoints only support Compute Engine (N1) machine types. You cannot use legacy (MLS1) machine types on regional endpoints.

As I can see, you have specified a regional endpoint with  the `--region` flag, which does not support the machine type you required for your use case. Thus, you need to change the model and its version to a global endpoint, so you won't face the error anymore.

In addition, when you specify a regional endpoint within `gcloud create model --region`, you need to specify the same region when creating the model's version. On the other hand, when creating a model in the global endpoint `gcloud create model --regions`, you can omit the region flag in the command `gcloud ai-platform versions create`. ***Note that the `--regions` command is used only for the global endpoint***

*Lastly, I must point out that, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/regional-endpoints#global-endpoint-region), when selecting a region for the global endpoint, using the `--regions` flag when creating the model, your prediction nodes run in the specified region. Although, the AI Platform Prediction infrastructure managing your resources might not necessarily run in the same region.*

Comment: @Jh123, please if you found the information useful, I would appreciate if you could  accept and upvote the answer above.